# What is the summation of 2+4+8+16+...+1024?

Tags: summation, algorithms

I am trying to figure out how to write the summation for 2+4+8+16+...+1024. Clearly my answer below is wrong by 1:

[image: Attempted answer]

I tried to apply the following summation formula but I guess I did not do it properly:

[image]

Please keep in mind I am not a mathy person. This is for an algorithm analysis course.

Comment: Note that your sum starts at $i=1$ but you try to use the formula for a sum starting at $i=0$.

Comment: The first sum is from $i=1 \to 10$, the second sum is from $i=0 \to 10$. Thus, you are missing out by the number $1$, which is just $2^0$.

Comment: I noticed the difference in i but I am not really sure how to be able to change the summation formula to account for that, like how I can change the summation formula to consider different values of i :S

Comment: @user3451821 $\sum_{i=0}^n a_n = a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n a_n$.

Comment: Just to clarify, if my i was in fact 2. Would I have to add a0, a1 to the summation in that case?

Comment: Yes, you would have to add the extra terms $a_0,a_1$ in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your summation is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{10}2^i=
2\sum_{i=1}^{10}2^{i-1}=
2\sum_{i=0}^{9}2^{i}=
2(2^{10}-1)=
2^{11}-2=2046
$$
Note the difference in the starting point between your problem and the formula you quote.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
2+4+8+\ldots+1024 &= x \\
2+2+4+8+\ldots+1024 &= 2+ x \\
(2+2)+4+8+\ldots+1024 &= 2+x \\
4+4+8+\ldots+1024 &= 2+x \\
(4+4)+8+\ldots+1024 &= 2+x \\
8+8+\ldots+1024 &= 2+x \\
&\ \vdots\\
1024+1024 &= 2+x \\
2048 &= 2+x \\
-2+2048 &= x
\end{align}

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: This is good method.

Answer (score 1):

The general formula for the sum of consecutive terms of a geometric series, not necessarily starting at $1$ is the following:
$$\sum_{k=m}^{k=n}q^k=\frac{q^{n+1}-q^m}{q-1}.$$
Factoring $q^m$ in the sum leads to applying the base formula with last exponent $n-m$, but it's worth knowing it for its own sake.

Answer (score 0):

"I noticed the difference in i but I am not really sure how to be able to change the summation formula to account for that, like how I can change the summation formula to consider different values of i :S "

The sumation index makes all the difference.

You can always do this:

$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i = \sum_{i=0}^k a_i + \sum_{i=k+1}^n a_i$ for any $0 < k < n$

So $\sum_{i=0}^2 2^i = 2^0 + \sum_{i=1}^n 2^i=$

$ 1 + \sum_{i=1}^n 2^i$ so $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^i = \sum_{i=0}^2 2^i - 1 = $

$(2^{n+1}-1) - 1 = 2^{n+1} - 2$.

....

and if you are really clever you can to this.

$\sum_{i=1}^n 2^i$; for each $i$ let's let $i = k+ 1$ so....

$\sum_{i=1;\text{ or } k = 0}^{i = n; \text{ or } k=n-1} (2^i=2^{k+1}) =$

$\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} 2^{k+1} =$

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2*2^k = 2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k=$

$2(2^n - 1) = 2^{n+1} - 2$.

You can sleep on the second part.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
2+4+8+\ldots+1024 &= \\
(-1+1)+2+4+8+\ldots+1024 &= \\
-1+(1+2+4+8+\ldots+1024) &= \\
-1 + \sum_{i=0}^{10}2^i \\
\end{align}

Now you can use the formula you mentioned.